# Why can an instance method be called as a module method after include?

Tags: ruby

An instance method defined on a module:

```
module A
  def foo; :bar end
end
```

seems to be able to be called as a module method of that module when that module is included:

```
include A
A.foo # => :bar
```

Why is that?

Comment: You're including A into Object.   Try Object.foo or Class.foo or 2.foo

Comment: But the context is `main`, which is an instance of `Object`, but not `Object` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're including A into Object.

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    puts base.inspect #Object
  end

  def foo
    :bar
  end
end

include A

puts A.foo # :bar
puts 2.foo # :bar

#puts BasicObject.new.foo   #this will fail
```

Also note that the top level object `main` is special; it's both an instance of Object and a sort of delegator to Object.

See http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/

Comment: Yes, I'm using that to show the caller.   BTW the top level object `main` is special, it's both an instance of Object and a sort of delegator to Object.   See http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/

Comment: I think the second sentence of your comment above is the most crucial part; the key to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this out in irb, it included it in `Object`. `include A` also returns `Object`

```
irb > module A
irb >   def foo; :bar end
irb > end
 => nil 
irb > Object.methods.include? :foo
 => false
irb > include A
 => Object
irb > Object.methods.include? :foo
 => true
```

Comment: You are just rephrasing my question.